# find hot region(spot) in spatial data

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, geospatial, data-science

I have a dataset about restaurant income data.
Each row of the dataset looks like:
`[restaurant_id, longitude, latitude, income]`

Now I want to find out geographical regions with highest restaurant income. E.g. the top 5 regions with high income.

I don't have a criteria about income, neither a criteria about what is a 'region'.

I have no experience dealing with this kind of data. I've thought about first building a heat map about income, then doing some image segmentation to find out hottest regions. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, try building a heat map.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Silencer 请问我的问题哪里不符合规范？

Comment: @Silencer 请大神指点一下怎么解决我的问题，跪谢！